# Compute limit of the sequence $x_n$ given by $x_{n+2}=-\frac{1}{2}(x_{n+1}-x_n^2)^2+x_n^4$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

Let $(x_n)$ be a real sequence such that $x_0=a\in\mathbb{R},x_1=b\in\mathbb{R},x_{n+2}=-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(x_{n+1}-x_{n}^2\right)^2+x_{n}^4\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N} $ and $|x_n|\leq \dfrac{3}{4},\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. The sequence $x_n$ is convergence or not and compute $\lim x_n$ (if exists)?

I think we could use $\inf$ and $\sup$. But I am not sure

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find rude writing a question that looks like it consists only of a verbatim quote; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: If the limit $L$ exists, then it has to satisfy $L=-\frac12(L-L^2)^2+L^4$ - do you see why? Once you have an idea what the limit is, it might make it easier to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Greg Martin stated in comment, the limit satisfies the equation $\displaystyle L=-\frac{1}{2}(L-L^2)^2+L^4$, not hard to find(by rearranging and factoring the equation) the solutions of the equation are $0,1,-1,-2$.

Because $\displaystyle |x_n|\leq \frac{3}{4}$ the sequence cannot converge to $1, -1, -2$. The sequence can only converge to $0$. It remains to prove the sequence indeed converges to 0, which can be done by estimating an descending upper bound of $|x_n|$

To do the estimation, we start by proving a lemma, for real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we have $|\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2+\alpha\beta-\frac{1}{2}\beta^2|\leq \frac{\sqrt2}{2}(\alpha^2+\beta^2)$.
To prove it, let $\gamma^2=\alpha^2+\beta^2$, we can parametrize $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to get $\alpha=\gamma \cos(\theta),\beta=\gamma \sin(\theta)$, which means $$\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2+\alpha\beta-\frac{1}{2}\beta^2=\frac{\gamma^2}{2}(\cos(2\theta)+sin(2\theta))=\frac{\sqrt2\gamma^2}{2}(sin(2\theta+\pi/4))$$ and therefore the inequality.

Back to the question, if $|x_n|\leq c$ and $|x_{n+1}|\leq c$, $\frac{3}{4}\geq c\geq 0$, by the lemma(set $\alpha=x_n^2$,$\beta=x_{n+1}$) $|x_{n+2}|=|-\frac{1}{2}(x_{n+1}-x_n^2)^2+x_n^4|=|\frac{1}{2}x_n^4+x_n^2x_{n+1}-\frac{1}{2}x_{n+1}^2|\leq|\frac{\sqrt2}{2}(x_n^4+x_{n+1}^2)|\leq\frac{\sqrt2}{2}(c^4+c^2)=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}(c^3+c)c\leq \frac{\sqrt2}{2}((\frac{3}{4})^3+(\frac{3}{4}))c<0.83c$

Therefore we get $|x_1|\leq\frac{3}{4},|x_2|\leq\frac{3}{4},|x_3|\leq(0.83)\frac{3}{4},|x_4|\leq(0.83)\frac{3}{4},|x_5|\leq(0.83)^2\frac{3}{4}......|x_{2n}|\leq(0.83)^{n-1}\frac{3}{4}$, where $(0.83)^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, by comparison we conclude the original sequence converges to 0.